# How to insert countdown into a video file

Tags: video-editor, clock

Is there an easy way to insert a big countdown clock after a given time position of a video file in linux? The countdown clock should count down in seconds from n to 0.

**Edit:**

I don't want to insert manually pictures showing the nth second. It is clear to me how to do that. What I want is an automatic way to do this:

- Set the number of seconds for the countdown (e.g. 64 or 80 seconds)
- Set the time where to insert the countdown in a given video

And finally get the video with inserted countdown at specified position as a result.

It would be nice if this would be possible in a graphical video editor like openshot. However it would also be ok to have a command line solution for this.

Comment: Install Openshot..

Comment: Howto do this with openshot?

Comment: In the openshot add img files. You can make your image files using gimp.

Comment: @GevorgHindoyan Is there any way to automate this? Making images and inserting them manually is ok if you do this one time for a video. However I need this feature very often and need countdown times ranging from 1 to 90 seconds...

Comment: @fossfreedom deleted my answer. =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a simple answer and I hope it will help you . You can use kdenlive !
after running it go to 
project>Generators>Countdown.
You can simply type your time and font and it will generate it for you .
nice time :)

Comment: My Kdenlive has the "Generator" option disabled. How to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to your question is:

```
NO.
```

There is no **easy** way to do this. You can use some tricks to annotate what a script will generate for you(the clock countdown) inside your video. Maybe Imagemagick and Bash will be a good start to you, but don´t expect some easy way without some

```
good code
```

. <- final dot.

Now, a solution using just **VIDEO EDITORS** (openshot, for example)

**3** steps to goal:

1. FIND **TIMECODE BURNER** ( Its a plugin to burn out timecode over video. Go google , this is easy if openshot doesnt have it native. ) RENDER SOME OF THIS PLUG IN (the time you need) with WHITE LETTERS, OVER BLACK SCREEN. ---->  *[you got your clock]*
2. IMPORT the result of item 1, and RENDER another movie with -100% speed
         (REVERSE IT) ----> *[you got your countdown]*
3. APPLY the countdown result of item 2 on your video, RENDERING the reversed burnout timecode video over the video you want it using LUMA KEY effect. (black screen will go out, white letters(your countdown) will show it over the video. ----> *[you got your video with countdown]*

Comment: hmmm as a hope, this good code will be pretty simple..

Comment: Ok, **easy** is matter of definition... however could co gives some more details of your idea

Comment: You can *easy find* some code to turn time into a countdown. Then, how to put this into your video, I am really lost as you. But I have another idea now. Gonna post another answer. =P

Comment: @fossfreedom Do you have a link for timecode burner? I didn't find it and I think openshot doesn't have this native.

Comment: ... no idea - I just edited in the information H_7 gave in his second answer (he should have just edited this one).

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to goal using command line:

1. find total length; for example: `mplayer -identify -endpos 00:00:00 videofile 2> /dev/null | grep ID_LENGTH`
2. make a script to create subtitles file (for example, in [SubRIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) format)
3. embed subtitles into video (using desired font, in desired position).